# APACHE FOP - The entity "deg" was referenced, but not declared

Tags: xml, xsl-fo, apache-fop

chrTemplateFileName ../laser_templates/pacPackingSlipESP-ESP.fo

```
                                                                              [INFO] Using org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser as SAX2 Parser
[INFO] Using org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser as SAX2 Parser
[INFO] FOP 0.20.5
[INFO] Using org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser as SAX2 Parser
[INFO] building formatting object tree
[INFO] setting up fonts
[ERROR] property 'xsi:nil' ignored
[ERROR] property 'xsi:nil' ignored
[Fatal Error] FopPckSlip20170320164044392.fo:89:101: The entity "deg" was referenced, but not declared.
[ERROR] The entity "deg" was referenced, but not declared.
Procedure complete. Press space bar to continue.
```

Comment: In future questions, consider adding more details to help reproduce the error (see [the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for good guidelines).

Comment: Also note you are using a really **old** version of FOP! Latest one is 2.1 (actually, a vote is currently active to release 2.2).

Answer (score 0):

Your input file apparently contains `&deg;`, which is a valid **HTML** entity but not a valid **XML** one (unless you declare it yourself).

You can replace it with the numeric entity `&#x00B0;`.